# Is standard ouput/error to a file a separate process? (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

The code I use to dump the standard error to a file is shown below:

```
    sudo COMMAND 2> FILENAME.txt
```

I want to be able to kill the COMMAND process by acquiring its PID and then using KILL like so:

```
    sudo COMMAND 2> FILENAME.txt &
    PID=$!
    sudo kill $PID
```

The question I have is, Am I killing the "Command" Process or am I killing the "dump error to file" Process??

If I am killing the "dump error to file" Process, how do I kill the actual Command Process?

Comment: I'm suggest to move it to superuser in stackexchange network

Comment: I think this belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I got my answer anyway. But I have a follow up question that I will post in the place you guys suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one process: the `sudo`.

1. The shell forks a new process, a child of the shell.
2. Its standard error is redirected to the file.
3. The command `sudo command` is `exec()`ed in the child process.
4. The parent stores the PID of the child process in `$!`.

`sudo` in turn sets up permissions according to its configuration, then performs another `exec()` to replace itself with `command`.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting standard IO to a file is not a process. You would be killing the `sudo` process, but the process should close the filehandle when it exits. That said, the redirect occurs before the `sudo` command is executed, so if your user account doesn't have permission to write `FILENAME.txt`, the shell will error out before ever executing the command.

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on

Comment: The filename.txt is being created so no issues with permission. The killing of the main Process is not happening for some reason. However I'll have to take the question elsewhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Every process, when started, inherits certain things from its parent process. One of those things is a set of open file handles (in POSIX, this includes at least standard input, standard output, and standard error, but others are possible as well). The redirection operators simply modify which file handles are passed to the new process.